# rails new project_name using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use rvm in my rails project and specify gem versions in the Gemfile.

However, my problem right now is different. I want to create a rails 3.1 project using `rails new project_name` but my current version of rails is `Rails 3.0.3`

I know I can just update my rails gem version but then will all future executions of `rails new project_name` create a 3.1 project?

How can I set things up so I can sometimes create rails 3.1 projects while other times creating rails 3.0 projects?

Comment: http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/

Comment: @bricker Doh! that was easy. if you make it an answer i'll mark yours as accepted

Comment: Okay, I've outlined the steps in an answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rvm 1.9.2
rvm gemset create rails310 rails303
rvm 1.9.2@rails310
gem install rails -v 3.1.0
rails new my_310_app

rvm 1.9.2@rails303
gem install rails -v 3.0.3
rails new my_303_app
```

http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/

Comment: on a related note, any idea how i could do the same thing with rbenv? i know rbenv doesn't do gemsets.

Comment: I'm not familiar with rbenv, sorry. Might be worth making another question with the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

If RVM is already installed.and ruby is also installed for required version.

You just have to run the fallowing command:

```
> rvm use 1.9.3
```

`1.9.3` is ruby version I wish to use.
Then ,

```
> rails new projectname
```

That's it!
Now, If you want to change rails verion of the project, Open folder of /Gemfile and change line below to any sepcified version .

```
 gem 'rails', '3.1.2'
```

Like if you want to use rails verison `3.0.5` then change `'3.1.2'` from line above to `'3.0.5'` and then run

```
 >`bundle install`
```

from command prompt.
It worked fine for me! Hope you also can also do this way!

Cheers!